# Merge different tex files

Tags: input, combine, files

I've already searched stackexchange but I couldn't find what I was looking for. The thing is that I have different .tex files (five in total, the main files), each of them includes other tex files. Every file is a volume (Volume 1, Volume 2..).
For Volume 1:

```
    \documentclass[...]
    \begin{document}
    \input{./sections/0_Intro}
    \newpage
    \input{./sections/2_part1}
    \newpage
    \input{./sections/3_part2}
    \newpage
    \input{./sections/4_part3}
    \newpage
    \input{./sections/5_part4}
    \newpage
    \input{./sections/6_part5}
    \end{document}
```

And the same applies for the other volumes. What I want to do is a single .tex document or PDF that includes all of them (including an index with all the volumes).
Is there anyway to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Easy stuff for Linux and a script, more difficult with LaTeX methods;-)

Comment: wouldn't that very document create a pdf which includes all of them? Also, instead of `input{file}\newpage`, you could just use `\include[file}`, which would start a new page for every single one, and you would also be able to use `\includeonly{file1}`.

Comment: Welcome! Your question isn't terribly clear to me right now. What is the structure of the file hierarchy exactly? What is the content of each currently `\input` file (structurally - not actually content)? What do you mean by `an index with all the volumes`? Do you mean that the index should combine `\index{<word>}` entries from each volume? Or do you not really mean an index but, say, a table of contents? Does each volume also get its own ToC and/or index? How should be pagination work? What about the bibliography? Are you already using `\part` for the `\input` files?

Comment: hey cfr. I have 5 files (or Volumes 1,2...), each file includes a "main_volume_number.tex", inside the "main_volume_number.tex" i use the input command to add the different chapters of the volume (\input{...}). What I want to do is merge in a single PDF/tex file all the Volumes (i.e. main_volume_1.tex + main_volume_2.tex + and so on), so I can have a single Table of contents/table of figures/ (yes, I meant ToC and not index). Is it more clear now? (English is not my first language xD)

Answer (score 1):

As an old emacs user there is a related feature in auctex, where the ToC can be listed together with the included files. Similar can be put in ToC of the document by also including the input files. Given the following files in `./Sections/`:

Input1.tex

```
\section{A section}
Text
\subsection{Sub section 1}
Text in subsection
```

Input2.tex

```
\section{A new section}
Text
\subsection{Sub section in new section}
Text in subsection
\input{Sections/Input21}
```

Input21.tex

```
\subsection{Yet another subsection}
Sub text
```

The main file adds a ToC line for each input file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\DEFinput\input
%\def\input#1{\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{*** #1 ***}\DEFinput{#1}} %% TeX style
\renewcommand\input[1]{\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{*** #1 ***}\DEFinput{#1}} %% LaTeX style

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\input{Sections/Input1}
\input{Sections/Input2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems ill-advised. Rather than redefine `\input`, just define (and via `\newcommand`) the command `\definput`: `\newcommand{\definput}[1]{\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{*** #1 ***}\input{#1}}`

Comment: @jon I agree, and that was my initial intention. However, there seem to be many nested inputs and my impression was that the need was to get some overview of them. In that case you would not like to replace the command everywhere, but rather to redefine `\input`. But I am not even sure I have understood the question completely. (About `\def` versus `\renewcommand` I would say they both have their plus and minus).

Comment: Replacing the command everywhere takes a matter of seconds using regexp. But using `\def` is dangerous for many people new to LaTeX.  (But I also don't understand the question.)

Comment: I have updated with `\renewcommand`

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative way available, instead of handling TeX or PDF file, you can go with merging PS files by using "**Runflex**", this is not an exact solution, but giving other alternatives...

Comment: Could you provide a link to this `Runflex`? A simple Google search doesn't yield anything of value.